# Springboot app cant lunch on vps, just on localhost

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have Springboot app, which can run on localhost, but when i export it in VSCode and try it run on vps, i get this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
```

My application.properties is:

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://myurl
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=mypass

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.maxRequestSize=10MB

#spring.servlet.multipart.location=
```

Can anyone help, thanks!

Comment: Export in VSCOde? That doesn't sound right... You need to use Maven or Gradle to build the jar not the export jar function of your IDE.

Comment: Yeah, i thought that could be problem, so you think, that my properties are not included?

Comment: It is the problem, not only your properties nor the jars that are needed. Spring Boot creates a special jar file and not a regular jar file (it has all the dependencies in it and some metadata) if you just export from your IDE that isn't there nor does the structure match.